# View all session in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, session

Can I view all active session(s) in my ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform this in global.asax:

```
private static object _syncRoot = new object();
private static List<string> _activeSessions = new List<string>();
public static ReadOnlyCollection<string> ActiveSessions
{
    get
    {
        lock(_syncRoot)
        {
            return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_activeSessions);
        }
    }
}

protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
        _activeSessions.Add(Session.SessionID);
    }
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(_syncRoot)
    {
        _activeSessions.Remove(Session.SessionID);
    }
}
```

and then use the `ActiveSessions` variable which will contain a list of all session ids.